# How to create Express middleware that runs right before res.render (template rendering)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to hook into the part right before Express templates are rendered (when res.render is called), so that I can do things like assign appropriate things from `res.` to `res.locals.`, making it available to the templates. For example, doing `res.locals.user = res.user`.

The standard middleware isn't good enough for this because it runs before everything, so in this case `user` wouldn't be available yet. Right now I have to do this in every route function separately.

```
res.locals.user = res.user;
res.render('template.html', context);
```

Also hooking in at this point would be useful for things like i18n, etc.

Comment: Disagree! A middleware is good for this, middlewares have their order and not all of them run each request, ex: move ```express.static``` to above will prevent lower middlewares from running.

Comment: Could you please give an example, `express.static` sounds interesting but I'm not sure what you mean, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The standard middleware isn't good enough for this because it runs
>   before everything

That is not correct, you can define where in the *chain* you put your middlewares, i.e (using `passport`):

```
//passport setup
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    ...
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(usr, done) {
    ...
});

// set locals
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // req.user is available
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

In this case `passport.session()` middleware will alter the `req` object to provide the user deserialised by `passport.deserializeUser` fn, making `req.user` available anywhere further in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a custom render function like this

```
function render(res) { 
    res.locals.user = res.user;
    res.render('template.html', context);
}
```

Comment: In every route function there would be a different template and context, along with slightly different things to pass from `res` to `res.locals`, so the function signature would be `function render(res, template, context, thingsToPassToResLocals)`, which would get quite unwieldy. Wondering if there's a simpler way?

Comment: Your function signature is better but i don't see any other way to do it(not exactly an expert).